# Rancher 2 disable HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, rancher

SSL redirect is enabled by default in a Kubernetes NGINX ingress on Rancher 2. We changed the config map and redeployed the nginx -ingres in the system namespace, but the redirect still happens. Has someone managed to disable it?

[image: nginx-configuration config map]

Comment: Did you try to use `ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` annotation in your ingress?
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect

Comment: hi, yes. with  ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" it still happens. i am note sure if the hsts header is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you will be able to `disable SSL` in `Rancher v2`.

As per [Randcher documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/other-installation-methods/single-node-docker/):

> For security purposes, SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is required when using Rancher. SSL secures all Rancher network communication, like when you login or interact with a cluster.

You can find there few ways to apply this certs:

- Default Rancher-generated Self-signed Certificate
- Bring Your Own Certificate, Self-signedlink
- Bring Your Own Certificate, Signed by a Recognized CA
- Let’s Encrypt Certificatelink

Inside this doc you have hyerlinks to further `Rancher docs`.

As `Rancher` by default deploying `nginx controller` you should also check [Rancher docs about Nginx Controller](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/add-ons/ingress-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

As an update, rancher can disable http -> https redirection by disabling ingress's TLS and set a custom header `"X-Forwarded-Proto: https"` from ingress controller -> rancher,
reference:
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/35088